# How to send notification for Restore object events in AWS S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sns, amazon-glacier

I am downloading archive files from AWS glacier. So i need to restore the objects from glacier to s3 first. Since i am using "expedited" mode, it's taking minutes to complete the restoration process. Then only i can download the file.

I have developed a react app to do this stuff. There is a "download" button which will perform restoration process. Then i need to send an email notification to the users (not a particular person) based on the completion of "Restore object events".

I refer to SNS notification and it says the way to send the notification to a particular email. But in my case i need to sen the mail to the one who clicked the "download" button.

How can i approach this? FYI :- I'm already using a lambda function as backend.

Please suggest an idea. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should consider using [AWS SES](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/Welcome.html) to send customized messages to individual users and to have more control over the email content and settings. This way, when, an object from glacier gets restored, the notification of this fact triggers a lambda function (you seem to already have such a function), which in turn will use **SES to send out an email** to your user.