# How to migrate data from s3 bucket to glacier?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

I have a TB sized S3 bucket with pdf files. I need to migrate the old files to glacier. I know that I can create a life cycle rule to migrate files which are older than certain number of days. But in my case currently the bucket consists of both old and new pdf files and they were added at a same time. So they may have same uploaded date. In this case a life cycle rule won't be useful.

In the pdf files there is a field called capture_date. So i need to migrate those files based on the capture_date. (ie: migrate all pdf files if the capture_date < 2015-05-21 likewise).

Will a Fargate job will be useful here? if so, please give a brief idea.

Please suggest your ideas. Thanks in advance

Comment: How big are these files? Can you process them in lambda?

Comment: each pdf will be around 10 mb

Comment: btw, forget the capture_date pick from pdf. because I can get it from my Elastic search index. Please suggest an idea to migrate without using a life cycle rule

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what you could do to address your issue?

Comment: Yes. Now i'm taking those capture_dates of those files from a ES cluster on aws. The issue is, since we only need to keep the files which are not older than 5 years (by capture_date) inside s3. For that reason i need a logic. Because by the time goes we may need to pick different file set to restore into s3. So i'm searching for a solution for it

Answer (score 2):

S3 by itself will not read your pdf files. Thus you have to read them yourself, extract data that determine which ones are old and new, and using AWS SDK (or CLI) to move them to Glacier.

Since the files are not too big, you could use [S3 Batch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/batch-ops.html) along with lambda function which would do the change of the class to glacier.

Alternatively, you could do this on an EC2 instance, using [S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/storage-inventory.html)'s CSV list of your objects (assuming large number of them).

And the most traditional way is to just list your bucket, and iterate over each object.

Comment: I will look into this. Thanks for the help. Can you give a solution to this also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67468404/how-to-send-notification-for-restore-object-events-in-aws-s3